# how remove @SuppressWarnings(“unused”) in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, suppress-warnings

I always see in many codes:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

How can I remove these lines I use in java (in the NetBeans IDE):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String newName1 = input.next();         
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String newFamily1 = input.next();           
String newGender1 = input.next();           
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String arrow = input.next();        
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String newName2 = input.next();         
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String newFamily2 = input.next();
String newGender2 = input.next();
```

Comment: Delete them. All they are is a hint to the IDE that the local variable is never referenced again. IMO if you're not using them it's a bit misleading to have variables--why not use a real parsing library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for it and replace all with ""

Comment: You mean execution errors : As far as I can see, you use input.next(). That looks like an Iterator/StringTokenier and it means that you're trying to go beyond the Iterator/StringTokenizer limit.
Use if(input.hasNext()/input.hasMore())  newFamily2 = input.next();

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need the variable and you're just trying to advance `input` just call `input.next()` and don't assign it to anything.